# $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^pf(x)=0$ for all $p\geq 0$, how to prove $f=0$ with the Fourier transform?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I found this as an exercise in Kolmogorov-Fomin, let me state the problem precisely:

Let $S_{\infty}$ be the space of functions on the real line for which there exists a colelction of constants $C_{pq}$ for all $p, q$ such that 
$$
|x^pf^{(q)}(x)|\leq C_{pq}.
$$
Is it true that if for all $p\geq 0$ $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^pf(x)=0$, then $f=0$?

The exercise follows a section on the Fourier transform of functions of $S_{\infty}$. Now, I guess one should prove this exercise (I am fairly sure it is true) using some properties of the Fourier transform, but I cannot see how.

So my question is, how is this to be proved with the fundamental properties of the Fourier transform in $S_{\infty}$?

Comment: Yes, it is actually a duplicate but I don't find the answer there particularly clear or useful.

Comment: The linked answer tells that (1) the given condition is equivalent to $\hat{f}^{(q)}(0) = 0$ for all $q \geq 0$, and that (2) you can indeed find a non-trivial function $f \in S_{\infty}$ for which this is satisfied by taking inverse Fourier-transform to some $g \in S_{\infty}$, for instance, $g(x) = \exp(-x^2-x^{-2})$.